# Не работает pybass

Tags: python, python-3.x

решил попрактиковаться, и написать mp3 плеер. Нашел уже знакомую либу "bass", в обертке для питона в виде "pybass".

Нашел пример, начал писать(все по серьезному, с модулем click), но звук не идет... В чем проблема?

```
import click;
import pybass as b;

@click.command()
@click.argument("filename")
@click.option(
    "--volume",
    "-v",
    help="Do i really have to explain this?"
)
def main(filename,volume):
    b.BASS_Init(-1,44100,0,0,0);
    handle = b.BASS_StreamCreateFile(False, filename, 0,0, b.BASS_DEVICE_DEFAULT);
    b.BASS_ChannelPlay(handle, False);
    foo = input();

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Проблема в том, что `main()` требует два аргумента, а вызывается вообще без аргументов. PS. В питоне точка с запятой не нужны.

Comment: @Эникейщик с чего ты взял что запускается без агрументов?  З.Ы. все не могу от других яп отвыкнуть

Comment: С того, что я не знал, что такое click :)

Answer (score 1):

Вы пробовали указывать filename ? Если да - проверьте  права на запись (`ls -lh`) 
Так же попробуйте проверить через:

```
from pygame import mixer

mixer.init()
mixer.music.load('filename')
mixer.music.play()
```

Если заработает - проблема в кодеках

Comment: На pygame работает... Подскажи куда копать? Мне звук с pygame жуть как не нравится. А если бы не указал filename, прога вообще бы не запустилась (ибо click)